# Android: Will a Timer tick regardless of the previous tick not yet being finished?

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I have used `Timer` to implement network operation every 30 seconds.

```
    Timer myTimer_30sn_send_alive = new Timer();
    myTimer_30sn_send_alive.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Send alive message on network
            // ....
        }

    }, 5000, 30 * 1000); // 30sn
```

If the network timeout was 40 seconds and the Timer was meant to tick again.

So the task may not be finished implementing the Task, the other tick time come.

I wonder Will the timer tick *regardless* the `TimerTask` operation finished or not !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple: no it doesn't. Although the TimerTask runs in it own thread it doesn't start a new tick before the other tick finishes.

You can validate this by using a test code like this and check the logcat for output.

```
    Timer testTimer = new Timer();
    testTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Test", "Tick: " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            SystemClock.sleep(10000);
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```